# Why the value of this kind of sequence always get bigger and then smaller

Tags: sequences-and-series

I tried to use $1$, $2$ and $3$ into this formula, and for all the answer will get bigger first than smaller. I want to know the reason for it.

[image]

Comment: The sequences are recursive sequences, as you might see. For example, in the first case,
$$
x_{n+1} = 1 + \frac{1}{x_n} \qquad \text{with } x_0 = 1
$$
So which one is bigger, $x_n$ or $x_{n+1}$? The limit of the sequence is
$$
\lim_{x \to \infty} x_n = \frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}  = \phi
$$
and if $x_n < \phi \Rightarrow x_{n+1} > \phi$ etc ... You can see this by comparing the functions
$$
f_1(x) = x
$$
and
$$
f_2(x) = 1+ \frac{1}{x}
$$ and figuring out when $f_1(x) > f_2(x)$.

Comment: The sequence contains the convergents of the (simple) continued fraction of the golden ratio $\ \ \varphi\ \ $. Such a sequence always alternates between values above and values below the given number.

Answer (score 1):

These are simple continued fractions. This from wikipedia tells you the approximation errors  alternate in sign:

> Corollary 1: The even convergents  continually increase, but are
>   always less than $x$.
>
> Corollary 2: The odd convergents  continually decrease, but are always
>   greater than $x$  .

(Good for you for noticing this.)

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continued_fraction#Properties